# Execution of 'System.Linq.Enumerable:GroupBy(IEnumerable`1,Func`2)' on the database server side currently not implemented

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, telerik, telerik-open-access

I am getting the error

> Execution of 'System.Linq.Enumerable:GroupBy(IEnumerable`1,Func`2)' on the database server side currently not implemented.

when I execute the following query

```
from t in dbContext.TrackerRecords
   where t.DeviceSerial.Value.Equals(deviceSerial) &&
   t.Date.Value >= fromDate && t.Date.Value <= toDate
   orderby t.Date.Value descending
   group t by t.Date.Value.Date into g
   select new TripDataModel
   {
      Day = g.Key,
      Trips = (from x in g
         group x by x.Date.Value.Hour into gj
         where gj.Max(m => m.Speed.Value) > 0
         let AvgSpd = gj.Average(m => m.Speed.Value)
         select new TripModel
         {
            MinSpeed = gj.Min(m => m.Speed.Value),
            MaxSpeed = gj.Max(m => m.Speed.Value),
            AvgSpeed = AvgSpd > 0 
                ? Math.Round(AvgSpd, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) 
                : 0,
            FromHour = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, g.Key.Day, gj.Key, 0, 0)
         })
   }
```

I tried the query in linqtosql and working fine but I need to use Telerik OpenAccess.

Is there any solution or workaround this?

Comment: can you group in memory, not at the server side?

Comment: Why to group in memory LinqToSql can group at server. why openAccess can not?

Comment: the error message leads me to think that linq group by hasn't been implemented in OpenAccess. And, assuming that it has own implementation (not using LinqToSql behind it), it is make sense you can use group by with LinqToSql but not with OpenAccess. **BUT**, after looking at [this forum discussion](http://www.telerik.com/forums/is-group-by-supported), I think group by should've been implemented in OpenAccess. Better try to post the question in that forum.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.telerik.com/forums/server-side-currently-not-implemented

After the first query, convert it to a list, then run the subquery.

like this:

```
from t in dbContext.TrackerRecords.ToList()
```

Then, the rest of your query.

Comment: If the query really can't be executed on the server side, then you shouldn't use `ToList` to evaluate it using Linq to objects, you should use `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: If you use `AsEnumerable` is it still executed on the database?